# yet another infinite useEffect() loop with axios

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

learning hooks and as many, I am stuck in an infinite loop while using useEffect(). Have tried all of the answers that where given here, on SO, but failed to implement them.

I am wondering more, because my previous app is working. Will put the code to both of them. Maybe someone can help me with my issue.

If those apps look familiar to someone, then yes, they come from a udemy course, but there they here made using setState and classes.

---

EDIT:

removed the object {} from

```
  useEffect(() => {
    onTermSubmit({});
  }, [])
```

I have added it during my search for an answer.

---

Infinite loop App:

[Code Sanbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/searchyoutubevideoapp-bb1yw?file=/src/components/App.js)

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import youtube from "../apis/youtube";
import VideoList from "./VideoList";

const App = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);

  const onTermSubmit = async (textInput) => {
    const response = await youtube.get("/search", {
      params: { q: textInput }
    });
    setVideos(response.data.items);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    onTermSubmit();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <SearchBar onFromAppSubmit={onTermSubmit} />
      <VideoList foundVideos={ videos } />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SearchBar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const SearchBar = ({onFromAppSubmit}) => {
    const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("");

    const onTextInputChange = event => {
        setTextInput(event.target.value);
    }

    const onFormSubmit = event => {
        event.preventDefault();

        onFromAppSubmit(textInput);
    }

    return(
    <div className="search-bar ui segment">
        <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
            <div className="field">
                <label>Video Search</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    placeholder="Type in to search for videos"
                    value={textInput}
                    onChange={onTextInputChange}
                    />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

VideoList.js

```
import React from "react";
import VideoItem from "./VideoItem";

const VideoList = ({foundVideos}) => {
    const renderedList = foundVideos.map((video) => {
        return(
            <VideoItem />
        );
    })

    return(
        <div>
            {renderedList}
        </div>
    );
}

export default VideoList;
```

VideoItem.js

```
import React from "react";

const VideoItem = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            VideoItem
        </div>
    );
}

export default VideoItem;
```

youtube.js

```
import axios from "axios";

const KEY = "myVerySecretKey^^";

export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3",
    params: {
        part: "snippet",
        type: "video",
        maxResults: 5,
        key: KEY
    }
});
```

---

And my working App:

App.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import unsplash from "../api/Unsplash";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
import ImageList from "./ImageList";


const App = () => {
  const [images, setImages] = useState([]);

  const onSearchSubmit = async (inputText) => {
    const response = await unsplash.get("/search/photos", {
      params: { query: inputText},
    });
    setImages(response.data.results);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
        onSearchSubmit();
  }, [])

  return (
    <div className="ui container" style={{marinTop: "10px"}}>

      <SearchBar whenSubmitted={onSearchSubmit} />
      <ImageList foundImages={images}/>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

SearchBar.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function SearchBar({whenSubmitted}){
    const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");

    function onInputChange(event){
        const writtenText = event.target.value;
        setInputText(writtenText);
    }

    function onFormSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();         //to prevent the form to refresh the whole form

        whenSubmitted(inputText);
    }

    return (
        <div className="ui segment">
            <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit} className="ui form">
                <div className="field">
                    <label>Image Search</label>
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        value={inputText}
                        onChange={onInputChange}
                        placeholder="Search"
                    />
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}

export default SearchBar;
```

Comment: Is it possible to show your videoList component because the above code doesn't seem to have anything that will cause an infinite loop

Comment: Hi, could you add a working CodeSandbox example? You can mock the axios call be just calling `setVideos(["some", "random", "items");`

Comment: Since there is only one useEffect and which has a deps array of empty will call only one time, with the above code didn't find any infinite loop, are you missing any part of the codeblocks ?

Comment: ok, will add all of my code.

Comment: Have made a codesandbox version. Thanks @Titulum for the hint!

Comment: @AaronErdwyn Your codesandbox demo doesn't go into an inifinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it turns out, that to get my desired result (show results only after I write something in the searchBar and press Enter/Return), I just need to erase the useEffect() function:

by Bobby B. (Teaching Assistant)

> useEffect is called on every render, so, when the app first loads its
>   getting called without a search term (which throws a 400). The
>   simplest solution would be to provide a default search term:
>
> ```
> useEffect(() => {
>     onSearchSubmit('cats');
>   }, []);
> ```
>
> Or you can remove it from the App.js entirely, if you were not looking
>   for this initial default image search feature.

I would have never thought, that one can skip the useEffect(). I was sure, that it is used in hooks as some kind of replacement for componentDidMount().

Thank you all for your kind help!

Answer (score 2):

The code looks correct, but I'm not sure why you have passed empty object from `useEffect` of your `app.js`.
Here:-

```
useEffect(() => {
    onTermSubmit({});
  }, [])
```

Your functions might be expecting a string.

Comment: Good point, I added it during my search for an answer and forgot to remove it before posting

Answer (score 1):

Please change your code in SearchBar.js like this

```
onChange={(evt) => onInputChange(evt)}
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: changed it to onChange={(event) => onTextInputChange(event)} but still no change :/.

Comment: Oh I forgot one thing. Please change for onFromSubmit as well. 
For events the style needs to be (param) => funcname(param)

Comment: Changed it now to:
    <form onSubmit={(event) => onFormSubmit(event)} className="ui form">    and     onChange={(event) => onTextInputChange(event)}

but did not help :/. Anyway thanks for your support :-)

Comment: I checked sandbox code and it's working. only one warning for uniqui keys, and that can be solved by key={index}. Let me know what's the issue on your code.

Comment: You are right! If you just could see my face now... Well, will investigate further with my vs code about the reason :/. Thanks also about the warning.

Answer (score 1):

You should make your `useEffect` dependent on your `searchValue`, so that the search gets triggered everytime a new `searchValue` is submitted:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import SearchBar from "./SearchBar";
// import youtube from "../apis/youtube";
import VideoList from "./VideoList";

const App = () => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState([]);
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState("");


  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      // const response = await youtube.get("/search", {
      //   params: { q: textInput }
      // });
      setVideos([searchValue, "some", "random", "items"]); //mocked the axios connection
    })();
  }, [searchValue]);

  return (
    <div className="ui container">
      <SearchBar
        onFromAppSubmit={newSearchValue => setSearchValue(newSearchValue)}
      />
      <VideoList foundVideos={videos} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[You can take a look at the updated sandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/searchyoutubevideoapp-172nl)

Comment: Well, is your searchValue not my textInput? I pass it over from SearchBar: const [textInput, setTextInput] = useState("");
A second thing is, that the search result appears (VideoItem) even before I have typed anything in the searchbar.

Comment: `textInput` is a state property in `SearchBar`. Your `uaeEffect` can not act on it, that's why you have to propagate it back up to your `App` component. There, the `useEffect` will see that it has changed, and execute the video loading with the new value. To fix the loading of the videos when no search term has been inserted, just add a check: `if (searchValue) { setVideos(/* your searched videos */); } else { setVideos([]); }`

Comment: But as I understan my app, I am passing the textInput in my SearchBar via onFormSubmit to my App.js where I use it so as you have described the [searchValue and setSearchValue]. Or am I wrong on this?